# How can I render an object on relation vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

This is my laravel:

```
$user->load('company', 'status', 'role');
return responseData($user);
```

This is my vue2 code:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:81/admin/users/get/${this.$route.params.id}`)
        .then(response => {
            this.user = response.data
        });
```

And v-model:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Company" v-model="user.company.name">
```

It still render company.name but get warning:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'name')"

Comment: Don't render the component until data is ready to use

Comment: Try to assign the user object with the full schema

Comment: First case : As per the error `company` is not available in the `users`. Hence, can you please console and check what `this.users` return ? Second case : Your template render before data is fetching from API. Can you please check and confirm which case is applying ? Based on that I can help you to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Estus Flask suggests,

The moment your component is mounted, you didn't receive the data yet.

Try to use a `v-if` directive on the input itself using optional chaining like this :

```
<input v-if="user?.company?.name" type="text" placeholder="Company" v-model="user.company.name">
```

It will check if user exists, then if company exists, then if name exists. If any doesn't exist it will not render the element.